# Unable to lock orientation ; possible fix?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-orientation

Trying to set orientation to `Portrait` only by default. To make it so, I've added:

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

However, the app auto rotates to `Landscape` mode when tilted. Furthermore, the app turns to `Landscape` mode when tilted even when the orientation is locked to portrait only in phone `Settings` .

Here is the `Manifest.xml` file :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.browser.codedady">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:fullBackupContent="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">

        <!-- Browser Main Tab -->

        <activity
            android:name=".Activity_Main"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

                <action android:name="readLater" />
                <action android:name="bookmarks" />
                <action android:name="history" />
                <action android:name="pass" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter
                android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:label="@string/app_websearch">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.shortcuts"
                android:resource="@xml/shortcuts" />
        </activity>

        <!-- Other activities -->

        <activity
            android:name=".about.About_activity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance" />
        <activity
            android:name=".helper.Activity_intro"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance" />
        <activity
            android:name=".helper.Activity_settings"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance" />
        <activity
            android:name=".helper.Activity_settings_app"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance" />
        <activity
            android:name=".helper.Activity_settings_data"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance" />
        <activity
            android:name=".helper.Activity_settings_searchMain"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance" />
        <activity
            android:name=".helper.Activity_settings_close"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance" />
        <activity
            android:name=".helper.Activity_settings_start"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance" />
        <activity
            android:name=".helper.Activity_settings_search"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance" />

        <!-- Intents -->

        <activity
            android:name=".helper.Activity_intent"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <data android:scheme="http" />
                <data android:scheme="https" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- More stuff -->

        <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.browser.codedady.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>

        <activity
            android:name=".Home"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_home"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

What could possibly be causing this and how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Add screenOrientation = "portrait" to each activity, like so:

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

Make sure your Java code does not alter the activity's orientation by accident. Configchanges doesn't set it to default, it asks the Java to be in charge of setting it. Remove those if they don't do anything else. [See android docs here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) (search for "android:configChanges")